# Splitting a variable length column in SQL server safely

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2005, select

I have a column (varchar400) in the following form in an SQL table :

```
Info
UserID=1123456,ItemID=6685642
```

The column is created via our point of sale application, and so I cannot do the normal thing of simply splitting it into two columns as this would cause an obscene amount of work. My problem is that this column is used to store attributes of products in our database, and so while I am only concerned with UserID and ItemID, there may be superfluous information stored here, for example :

```
   Info
   IrrelevantID=666,UserID=123124,AnotherIrrelevantID=1232342,ItemID=1213124.
```

What I want to retrieve is simply two columns, with no error given if neither of these attributes exists in the `Info` column. :

```
UserID ItemID
123124 1213124
```

Would it be possible to do this effectively, with error checking, given that the length of the IDs are all variable, but all of the attributes are comma-separated and follow a uniform style (i.e "UserID=number").

Can anyone tell me the best way of dealing with my problem ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you have any id defined on the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @infotable table (info varchar(4000))
insert into @infotable
select 'IrrelevantID=666,UserID=123124,AnotherIrrelevantID=1232342,ItemID=1213124.'
union all 
select 'UserID=1123456,ItemID=6685642'

-- convert info column to xml type
; with cte as
(
    select cast('<info ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(info,',', '" '),'=','="'),'.','') + '" />' as XML) info,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by info) id
    from @infotable
)
select userId, ItemId from 
(

       select T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') as Name,
       T.N.value('.', 'varchar(max)') as Value, id
       from cte cross apply info.nodes('//@*') as T(N)
) v
pivot (max(value) for Name in ([UserID], [ItemId])) p
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16199)

Comment: My problem is that there can be spaces in the ids now, so it can be "User ID=12323" rather than "UserID=223123". I added an extra REPLACE to the beginning of the initial SELECT, replacing a ' ' with a '', however I now get the message : 
XML parsing: line 1, character 123, equal expected - even though it works on the fiddle I have made; and even when I run it in SQL Server Management Studio it returns a set of values for a second - and then displays the error message.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16255 Link to my functioning SQL script. I am running the same in SQL Server Management Studio 2005 but cannot for the life of me figure out why it will not return any values.

Comment: can you run select * cte and post values you get?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this split function:  http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ItemID=1213124. is terminated with a dot.

```
Declare @t Table (a varchar(400))
insert into @t values ('IrrelevantID=666,UserID=123124,AnotherIrrelevantID=1232342,ItemID=1213124.')
insert into @t values ('IrrelevantID=333,UserID=222222,AnotherIrrelevantID=0,ItemID=111.')

Select 
STUFF(
Stuff(a,1,CHARINDEX(',UserID=',a) + Len(',UserID=')-1 ,'' )
,CharIndex
(',',
Stuff(a,1,CHARINDEX(',UserID=',a) + Len(',UserID=')-1 ,'' )
) 
,400,'') as UserID

,
STUFF(
Stuff(a,1,CHARINDEX(',ItemID=',a) + Len(',ItemID=')-1 ,'' )
,CharIndex
('.',
Stuff(a,1,CHARINDEX(',ItemID=',a) + Len(',ItemID=')-1,'' )
) 
,400,'') as ItemID
from @t
```